# C to C# CRC calculation convertor

Tags: c#, c, crc, crc16

I have a code in C
which I need to rewrite it in c#

however in C# there are not pointers

how can I do this conversion?

Thank for all answers

```
unsigned int CCITT_CRC_TAB[256] = {         // CCITT CRC-16 polynomial table
0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50A5, 0x60C6, 0x70E7,
};
unsigned int CalcCrc16( unsigned int* ptr_res , unsigned char * 
BufStart,unsigned char BufLen)
{
 unsigned int CRCres,V1; // 16 bit var
 unsigned char * BufPtr;  // 8 bit var

    BufPtr = BufStart;
    for(CRCres = 0 ;BufPtr < (BufStart + BufLen) ;BufPtr++)
  {
    V1 = (unsigned int)((CRCres>>8)^ *BufPtr);
    CRCres  = (unsigned int)((CRCres>>8)^ CCITT_CRC_TAB[V1]);
  }

*ptr_res = CRCres;
}
```

Comment: use a `byte[]` or `Stream` instead of dealing with pointers.

Comment: *however in C# there are not pointers* actually C# [does have pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/)

Comment: The C code could have used some cleanup as well ;-) It seems the writter wasn't clear whether he wanted an out argument (int *ptr_res) or a return value. The later isn't assigned at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# way (assuming that the callers will be migrated as well or are allready C#):

```
uint CalcCrc16(byte[] BufStart, byte BufLen)
{
    uint CRCres = 0, V1 = 0; // 16 bit var
    for(int i = 0 ; i < BufLen; i++)
    {
        V1 = (uint)((CRCres>>8) ^ BufStart[i]);
        CRCres  = (uint)((CRCres>>8)^ CCITT_CRC_TAB[V1]);
    }
    return CRCres;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add `unsafe` code and add project settings if you use VisualStudio.

```
unsigned unsafe int CalcCrc16(uint* ptr_res , byte *BufStart, byte BufLen)
{
    uint CRCres,V1; // 16 bit var
    byte * BufPtr;  // 8 bit var

    BufPtr = BufStart;
    for(CRCres = 0 ;BufPtr < (BufStart + BufLen) ;BufPtr++)
    {
        V1 = (uint)((CRCres>>8)^ *BufPtr);
        CRCres = (uint)((CRCres>>8)^ CCITT_CRC_TAB[V1]);
    }
    *ptr_res = CRCres;
}
```

Comment: NO unsigned int and no unsigned char

Comment: Sorry, please use `uint` and `byte`.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Don't use unsafe code unless you have to.